# Required sample size $n$

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size

How can I estimate the required sample size $n$ from a population of unknown standard deviation $\sigma$, in order to estimate the mean of a variable, given the margin of error $\epsilon$ and a confidence level $1- \alpha$ ?

For instance, if my sample follow Poisson distribution, with parameter $\lambda$, we can construct a confidence interval of this parameter with:
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}P( \lambda \in [ \bar X_n - t_{\alpha}S_n/\sqrt n, X_n + t_{\alpha}S_n/\sqrt n]) = 1-\alpha \tag1$$  where $S_n$ is the empirical standard deviation.
Then $\epsilon = 2 t_{\alpha} S_n/\sqrt n$
($ \epsilon = 2 t_{\alpha} \sigma/\sqrt n $  if $\sigma$ was known )
And so $n = \frac{4 t_{\alpha}^2S_n^2} {\epsilon^2}$ where $S_n$ depends on $n$ ... which we want to evaluate.
And even step $(1)$ bothers me, when I give a confidence interval I"forget" to mention the limit, i just say $\lambda$ is in the interval $ [ \bar X_n - t_{\alpha}S_n/\sqrt n, X_n + t_{\alpha}S_n/\sqrt n]$  with a probability of $ 1 - \alpha$.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: In my work I have some data, on these data I am able to build confidence intervals on calculated statistics, proportion or mean. Now we want to know how much data we need to reduce the error with a fixed confidence level

Comment: What information and assumptions do you have available to estimate $n$?  You need *some* information about $\sigma.$

Comment: Then, there is no way to estimate $n$ without information on $\sigma$ ?

Comment: At the moment your question is ambiguous, largely due to a lack of clarity in what you are seeking and what you already know.  I suspect that you are using $n$ here to refer to the *required minimum sample size* for a particular inference, not the population size (contrary to how you have written it) and that you are looking at this problem *a priori* ---i.e., before you see any data.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Ben Yes you are right!  It's the sample size not the population size, i misspoke

Comment: You can do this for Poisson since the mean and variance are both $\lambda$. Not many other distributions have variance that is a function of the mean, so you need to do a pilot or make assumptions.